# get to next tbody from tr

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a need where from a specific `<td>` , I need to get the next `<tbody>` and showToggle is with jQuery. The nesting looks like below

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="fromhere">something</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="tohere">
     <tr>
         <td>Something</td>
     <tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to trigger "tohere" when "formhere" is clicked using jquery.

I tried `$('.fromhere).next('tbody').showToggle(100)` but that does not work. The reason I am doing classes is I have multiple such tbody combos and I don't want to right an on click for each which is not good coding practice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try with `.parent()` and `.next()` like

```
$('.fromhere').parent('tbody').next('tbody').showToggle(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to traverse upward till the current element's `tbody` then find the next element from there. You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse upward

```
$('.fromhere').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tbody').next('tbody').slideToggle(100)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U7w6Q/)